# Trouble installing basemap on ipython

Tags: ipython, python-3.3, python-3.4, matplotlib-basemap

I've got IPython installed for both python3.3 and python3.4

When I tried to install basemap using conda install basemap I keep receving the two same errors saying there is a conflict.

Hint: the following combinations of packages create a conflict with the
remaining packages:
  - python 3.3*
  - basemap

Hint: the following combinations of packages create a conflict with the
remaining packages:
  - python 3.4*
  - basemap

Is basemap not supported by those two version of python? Do I need to move to python2.7 to get basemap to work? Or is there a different way to install basemap on ipython?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the installer(.exe) (http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/download.html) if you are Windows User

Answer (score 0):

Basemap is available now for python 3.3 on windows, so this should no longer by an issue for you.  I was having problems on python 3.5 and had to use pip to install the wheel file from here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Worked with the basemap group to find a way to install it:
https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/249